# Вопрос по ООП

Tags: ооп, java

```
class Parent { 
    int a = 1;
    void a() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
     int a = 2;
}

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

         (new Child()).a();

    } 
}
```

Выводится 1.

Собственно вопрос: как достать ту **а**, которая **а=2**

p.s. наследников у **Parent** будет несколько, значит решение должно быть универсальное, т.е. не только для **Child**, но и для всех других

Comment: @danpetruk: Вам не должно хотеться из метода родительского класса иметь доступ к полям производного класса: это признак неправильного дизайна.

Вам может хотеться пользоваться результатов виртуального метода, как рекомендует @falstaf.

Comment: @VladD, неправильного дизайна? Давайте я расскажу, какая у меня ситуация, а вы скажете, как надо было бы поступить. 

Итак, у меня есть класс Level, который отвечает за прорисовку элементов, одинаковых для всех уровней, плюс куча его наследников - по уровню на каждого. 

Из этих, одинаковых для всех уровней элементов, есть элемент, отвечающий за переход на следующий уровень. Если след. уровень пройден - он белый, нет - серый. Для того чтобы определить пройден ли след уровень, мне надо знать уровень того, который открыл пользователь. Поэтому я обращаюсь к полю производного класса

Comment: @danpetruk, добавьте метод `int getLevel()` или что-то типа того, и пусть каждый наследник его перегружает. Таким образом, родительский класс при вызове `getLevel()` получит значение, возвращаемое потомком.

Comment: @falstaf, это я понял, об этом и ваш ответ. Просто @VladD говорит о неправильном дизайне, с чем я и пытаюсь поспорить

Comment: @danpetruk, а тут, на самом деле, не о чем спорить. То, что вы изначально собирались сделать — грубое нарушение принципов ООП.

Comment: @falstaf ну а как тут выкрутиться, не нарушая правила ооп?

Comment: @danpetruk, я же вам выше в комментарии уже дал ответ.

Comment: @falstaf, @danpetruk все выше описанное вполне помещается в паттерн Template Method.

Comment: @danpetruk: @falstaf ответил за меня.

Если у вас значение `a` в исходном классе и классе-наследнике разное, то не обязательно заводить новое _поле_, просто присвойте ему разные _значения_ в конструкторе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавить к классу `Parent` метод

```
int getA() {
    return a;
}
```

. В наследниках, при необходимости, перегружать его.

Answer (score -1):

Можно добавить дефолтные конструкторы в классы и создавая объекты классов, вызывать не метод, а переменную у созданного объекта.

```
Child child = new Child();
System.out.println(child.a);
```

Вывод:

> 2

Comment: > вызывать не метод, а переменную

@Cooler, в "вопросе по ООП" вы покушаетесь на инкапсуляцию?

Comment: я ТС-у альтернативный вариант предложил, по инкапсуляции пусть уже сам решает, геттеры добавляет и т.д.